# Cause of only hot or cold water from bathtub faucet?

Tags: water, faucet

I'm only getting extremely hot water or extremely cold water out of the bathtub faucet. the sink in the bathroom is fine. What causes this?

Answer (score 3):

Usually a bad **cartridge** in the control valve.

Those can be replaced, with more or less trouble depending on design and the particular installation.